# UILabel's width is exceeding the text using programmed Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

So I have two UIViews, a `UILabel` and a `UITextField`, the first one is the title of the field, second is where the info will be typed.. This is how I'm setting their AutoLayout Constraints:

For the input field:

```
 //Constraints:
    inputField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    //Setting trailing = superview(which is called self)'s trailing +2.0
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputField, 
    attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: self, attribute: .trailingMargin, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2.0).isActive = true;

    //Set Top = superview(which is called self) top -2.0
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputField, 
    attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: self, attribute: .topMargin, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: -2.0).isActive = true;

    //Setting the height = 30
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputField, attribute: .height, 
    relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30).isActive = true;
```

Then for the UILabel (called `emailLabel22`):

```
//Constraints:
    //      Left
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailLabel22, 
    attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: self, attribute: .leadingMargin, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 2.0).isActive = true;

    //      Buffer Right
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailLabel22, 
    attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: inputField, attribute: .leading, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0).isActive = true;

    //      Align Tops
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailLabel22, 
    attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: inputField, attribute: .top, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true;

    //      Height
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailLabel22, 
    attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 30).isActive = true;

    //      Buffer Right -- **For Input Field**
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputField, 
    attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: emailLabel22, attribute: .trailing, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0).isActive = true;

    //      Locking in Width??? (Should I use this?)
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailLabel22, 
    attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, 
    toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: emailLabel22.frame.size.width);
```

The gist of the code above is this: inputField is right-aligned to the superview (`self`). Email is left aligned. They then have a gap between them for aesthetics.

**This is the problem:**

If I set `emailLabel22` first, then it's width becomes huge and input field is squished to the right side of the screen with a lot empty space between them. [Like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9Zc.jpg)

If I set the input field first, as in the code above, I then squish email down to its locked in width, which in this case is 73. Which means any text that doesn't fit into the 73pt width is truncated with ellipsis. [Like So](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFfbG.jpg)

If I remove the lock down on the width of e-mail, the inputField's size expands if I type in words that don't fit in the textfield. [Like So](https://media.giphy.com/media/yqAQDqS1AyMjm/giphy.gif)

This wouldn't really be a problem, but I'm trying to build a robust label/text field combo that I can set any text to and have it fit perfectly, so I don't want to have to "Lock Down the Width" of the Email Label. I want it to expand as much as it wants to the right, but within the text size. I also don't want the inputField to squish down the email label. I also don't want to squish down the email's font size, input squishing down is fine.

I've been trying to fix this for 3 hours. I have no idea how to.

Thanks.

Comment: It's late night where I'm at so I don't have the time to help, but Apple actually has some good documentation about "intrinsic size" that looks like it may help: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try set hugging and commpresion resistance priority on your UILabel and UITextField

[image]

Comment: I've never known how to use those! Now I know!! Thank you so much (:

Comment: I also never remember, so I have this image always at the computer

Comment: Do you mind sharing where you got this image from? I love it!

Comment: I got this image from https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real but I modified it

Comment: What a useful website! Thanks again.